# How to Get a Column to Display the Next Sequential Number Based on Imported Data

Tags: sequential

I have an issue and from what I was told, it was **IMPOSSIBLE** to do. Below are the details.

I'm importing data from a CSV file into a SharePoint 2010 list. This is no problem as I have done it successfully.

Within the CSV file I have a column called RequestNumber. This column starts with the number 7999 and ends with 9437.

I'm importing this into my list and populating a column called RequestNumber. I kept the column names the same to keep it simple.

The desired is that when a user adds a new item to the list I want the next sequential number to display 9438.

Think of the default ID column where it displays the ID sequentially and start with the ID number 1.

However, in my case, the column will start with the number 7999.

Is this an impossible feat to achieve or is there a way to make this happen?

I can use a workflow or anything else if advised. I just want to know if this was IMPOSSIBLE as my colleague has told me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve it through workflow.

1. Create SharePoint list workflow with the help of designer
2. Enable workflow setting to trigger when an item adding to the list.
3. Take current item Id and then minus (-) one value from current item ID.
4. Now you have previous item ID, with that take previous item ID “RequestNumber”
5. Increment one number from previous Request number
6. Update current item field "RequestNumber" with incremented value.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

If your Excel sheet is 7999 to 9438 (all sequential) you want to force the ID to start from 7999

Then use Code or Workflow to:

- create an Item
- delete an item

Until you reach ID=7998

then import your CSV